Movie about criminals who kidnap a group of hiking tourists
This should hopefully be a pretty easy one. I tried googling but am coming up empty. I'm trying to remember a movie I saw as a kid, it would have been in the 80's or early 90's. It is about a group of hikers who end up getting taken hostage by either a group of criminals or possibly just one who is a sociopath. He pretends to be just a normal hiker at first and at one point another hiker is falling off a cliff and he is holding his hand but instead of pulling him up he lets him fall. None of the other hikers see this happen so he tells them it was an accident and he pretends to be upset that he couldn't save the other guy. I also seem to remember that the leader of the tourist group was a woman. 
There are also two detectives that are trying to find the group in the mountains and at one point they end up getting caught in a snow storm and did a snow cave and I remember there is a scene after the storm where one of them punches through the snow from the cave and we see all this from the outside. The last detail is that one of the detectives is a well known African American actor but I can't remember who it is.
No it isn't Cliffhanger or The River Wild but it is the same type of movie.

A compilation of kidnapping and hostage movies in no particular order. I love kidnapping movies, the thrill, the excitement the horror! So if I missed any please let me know :)http://www.imdb.com/list/ls000011555/ African American actor : http://www.imdb.com/list/ls077130929/

Deadly Pursuit (IMDB) aka Shoot to Kill (Wikipedia) from 1988 starring Sidney Poitier and Tom Berenger. 
Plot details from Wikipedia matching your question:

Stantin becomes obsessed with finding Steve, and he chases Steve into the rugged forests of the state of Washington, where Steve joins up with a group of sportsmen who plan to trek into the wilderness on a fishing trip. Steve's plan is to kill them and force their guide, Sarah (Kirstie Alley), to lead him through the wilderness to the Canadian border.
The killer's identity is not revealed until midway through the film. He attempts to evade detection by killing a member of a hiking expedition and taking his place. 


Oh yeah I think that's it! Going to find a copy and watch to check but I think this is it. Thanks!

@sanpaco You are welcome, glad I could help
